# Connecting to Cloud Redis Instance using Lettuce

Tags: java, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, redis, lettuce

I have a Redis Memoryspace instance in Google Cloud and I'm trying to connect to it from my Java App. If I try to connect to it using google cloud shell i succeed using these commands:

```
gcloud container clusters get-credentials CLUSTER_NAME --zone CLUSTER_ZONE --project PROJECT_ID
kubectl run -i --tty redisbox --image=gcr.io/google_containers/redis:v1 -- sh
redis-cli -h HOST-IP
```

This is my Java connection class:

```
@Configuration
public class RedisConfig {


    @Value("${spring.data.redis.port}")
    private int redisPort;

    @Value("${spring.data.redis.host}")
    private String redisHost;

    @Bean
    public RedisStandaloneConfiguration redisStandaloneConfiguration() {
        return new RedisStandaloneConfiguration(redisHost, redisPort);
    }

    @Bean
    public ClientOptions clientOptions(){
        return ClientOptions.builder()
                .disconnectedBehavior(ClientOptions.DisconnectedBehavior.REJECT_COMMANDS)
                .autoReconnect(true)
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    LettucePoolingClientConfiguration lettucePoolConfig(ClientOptions options, ClientResources dcr){
        return LettucePoolingClientConfiguration.builder()
                .poolConfig(new GenericObjectPoolConfig())
                .clientOptions(options)
                .clientResources(dcr)
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public RedisConnectionFactory connectionFactory(RedisStandaloneConfiguration redisStandaloneConfiguration,
                                                    LettucePoolingClientConfiguration lettucePoolConfig) {
        return new LettuceConnectionFactory(redisStandaloneConfiguration, lettucePoolConfig);
    }



    @Bean
    public RedisTemplate<String, Object> redisTemplate(RedisConnectionFactory redisConnectionFactory) {
        RedisTemplate<String, Object> redisTemplate = new RedisTemplate<>();
        redisTemplate.setConnectionFactory(redisConnectionFactory);
        return redisTemplate;
    }
}
```

But when I try to do anything like this:

```
redisTemplate.getConnectionFactory().getConnection().ping();
```

I get the following error:

```
org.springframework.data.redis.RedisConnectionFailureException: Unable to connect to Redis; nested exception is org.springframework.data.redis.connection.PoolException: Could not get a resource from the pool; nested exception is io.lettuce.core.RedisConnectionException: Unable to connect to (my host)/<unresolved>:6379
```

How can I connect to my Redis Memoryspace instance locally?

Comment: Please check these documentation on [client library connection code samples](https://cloud.google.com/memorystore/docs/cluster/client-library-connection) and [connecting to a Redis instance from a Google Kubernetes Engine cluster](https://cloud.google.com/memorystore/docs/redis/connect-redis-instance-gke). You may also check this documentation on [errors when connecting to an instance using a Google Kubernetes Engine cluster](https://cloud.google.com/memorystore/docs/redis/troubleshoot-issues#errors_when_connecting_to_your_instance_using_a_cluster).